# Codename one: Why does the android button have a different appearance than the IOS button

Tags: css, codenameone

I am currently styling my App with the css plugin for codename one and I cannot figure out why the default look of the Button is different for android and IOS.

In IOS it looks like this:

[image: Button in IOS]

In Android it looks like this:

[image: Button in Android]

It should look like it does in IOS for all devices.

In the Css file, I have this entry for Button:

```
Button {
    cn1-derive: Button;
    background-color: #005EA8;
    color: white;
}

Button.unselected {
    cn1-derive: Button.unselected;
    background-color: #005EA8;
    color: white;
}

Button.pressed {
    cn1-derive: Button.pressed;
    background-color: white;
    color: #005EA8;
}
```

Its not just the Login Button that should look like this, but All buttons. None of the Buttons looks like they should on Android, but all look like it in IOS.

In Addition, as you might notice, the look changes on click. In IOS this works as expected, In Android **the text color changes on click to #0005ea8**, but the background is still this grey.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Because buttons are given different syles by different operating systems.

Comment: @Paulie_D but there needs to be a way to force same behaviour, neednt it?

Comment: @Paulie_D okay, I know what you mean. 

The problem is, that I am overwriting the Styles of **all** operating systems whenever I enter something as a CSS file. All the other problems occured when using the UIBuilder or plattform specific resources. As I am using the CSS Plugin, it **should** overwrite ALL settings. At least there is no possibility to tell the file to only overwrite the settings of one specific plattform. **EDIT** overwriting all styles with the css file works for other parts of the app, like the ToolBar as well, so why not for buttons?

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the ugly parts of CSS meets CN1 themes.  The problem is that your CSS theme is being applied over top of the CN1 native theme.  Any properties that you set on Button will override whatever those properties were in the native theme, but there are other properties of Button from the native theme that you are not overriding.

Further, CN1 styles offer three ways to set the "background" of the component.  In ascending order of priority, they are:

1. Background color
2. Background (image)
3. Border  (9-piece borders effectively set the entire background).

If you apply two of these in the same style, then the one lower on the list (higher in number) will take priority.  E.g. if you set both the background color and a 9-piece border, then you won't see the background color at all - you'll just see the 9-piece border.

So what is happening here is that you've set the background color for your button in CSS, but the native theme likely set a background image, or a 9-piece border on the Button style which is still overriding your settings.

There are a couple of solutions to your problem:

Solution 1: Override the other "background" properties

Set `border: none` (to ensure that you override any 9-piece border)  (or set border to something).  And specify the `cn1-background-type: none` to ensure that there isn't an image background being applied to it:

`Button {
    background-color: #005EA8;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cn1-background-type: none;
}`

NOTE: You also don't need to specify `cn1-derive: Button` because your style name actually *is* Button.

Solution 2: Create your Own Button classes from the ground up

If you don't want the baggage of the native theme, just create your own style, and set it exactly how you want.

e.g.

`MyButton {
    ...
}`

And in your Java code:

`btn.setUIID("MyButton");`

Comment: okay, so I tried both solutions for two similar problems. The first option, setting the background to `none` worked. When I have a Label and want it to have a transparent background, I tried the second one, creating my own Style `myLabel`, but it still hase a grey background, why?